# Informatica MDM: Failing to clean inter-op lock records

Tags: informatica, mdm, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am trying to call PUT method from my java service to BES, this works but its taking ~10 secs to get the response. I am seeing below error in the logs; wondering this would be causing the delay in getting the response.

```
[default task-28] [ERROR] com.informatica.mdm.api.AbstractSifCall: failing to clean inter-op lock 
records
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.informatica.mdm.api.put.Put.releaseLocks(Put.java:303)
```

This is how my REST call looks like:

```
HTTP PUT
http://infmdm:8080/cmx/cs/ecm-ECM_ORS/PartyContact/4960299.json?systemName=CRM

json body

{
  "firstName": "James"
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Few comments, it looks like java api issue. Did you test the api using tools like swagger? Sometime user tahts running Informatica services doesn't have proper accessess and api call can throw up some error.

Comment: @KoushikRoy: Thanks for the hint, I tested through some rest client; call works but I was expecting quicker response. I see POST calls working faster

Comment: oh, ok performance is something depends on many things. But if i were you, i will start from api and swagger. Informatica just calls the api. Now, api perf is always poor because it goes through lots of hoops.